# Kaplan–Meier survival curves vs Nelson–Aalen cumulative hazard curves: interpretation

Tags: survival, hazard, kaplan-meier

I have a right-censored data set. I plot a Kaplan–Meier survival curve using R:
[image: Kaplan-Meier survival curve]

The y-values are easy to interpret, e.g. about 45% of the population will survive 500 days.

Now I plot the Nelson–Aalen cumulative hazard curve by setting the parameter `fun="cumhaz"` in the `plot` function:
[image: Nelson–Aalen cumulative hazard curve]
Do the y-values have any intuitive interpretation in this case? Are there any advantages to the latter plot in a presentation?

Comment: One "intuitive" interpretation of the cumulative hazards I know of is: if we assume that a subject under observations is immediately revived when he dies then the cumulative hazards at time t measures the expected amount of observed deaths.

Comment: Does this mean that when y=1, x is the expected (mean) lifetime? I thought it was not possible to calculate the expected lifetime when censored data is present.

Comment: No that doesn't seem right to me, but I dug around a bit and found this stackexchange post which explains the cummulative hazards better than I can, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60238/intuition-for-cumulative-hazard-function-survival-analysis